# Redirecting www.subdomain.domain.com to domain.com with htaccess

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, redirect

So I'm trying to get my server configured in a specific way so that anyone who visits http://www.subdomain.domain.com or https://www.subdomain.domain.com gets redirected to https:// without the www.

What Htaccess would I need to achieve this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If I visit https://www.subdomain.com that isn't redirecting to https://subdomain.com

Comment: Then edit your question and clearly define what do you want.

Comment: Pretty sure my question included the https:// part.... The example is https://www.clients.evaske.com/. I need that to link to https://clients.evaske.com as you can see if you click the link it throws up an SSL error.

Comment: You're going to get the SSL error with that cert unless you get a cert that matches *.clients.evaske.com.  The rewrite only takes place AFTER the cert is presented.

Comment: Is there no way to make it redirect before the certificate request?

Comment: Agree with @TheCleaner. It won't solve this particular problem...